# Splitting locale index.json into separate files?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm expanding a working Azure Bot Service prototype (on an App Service Plan) that contains all of its prompts in ./locale/en/index.json. Is it possible to split that into multiple files and programmatically determine which file we check for prompts at runtime? Would this cause significant unexpected performance impacts?

Example: if I had different responses to "what is an apple" and "what is an orange", defining both as fruitDefinition prompt in separate files (apple.json and orange.json.)

Instead of:

```
bot.dialog(('Apple', [
     function (session, args, next) {
         session.send("prompt_define_apple");
    }
]).triggerAction({matches: 'Apple'});
```

This would allow me to be more generic with the code, pulling the same prompt name each time ("prompt_define") and just varying what file I take it from.

I could certainly keep dumping everything in the index.json but the prompt namespace is already getting a bit cluttered, and I'd like to scale this to a wide set of entities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is by using Libraries. By doing that you can have a localization file for each of the libraries.

In the [Contoso Flowers sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers), you will find this implemented.

**To create the library ([index.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers/bot/index.js))**

```
bot.library(require('./dialogs/shop').createLibrary());
```

**To define the library ([shop.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers/bot/dialogs/shop.js))**

```
var lib = new builder.Library('shop');
lib.dialog('/', [..]);
```

**Localizable file ([shop.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers/bot/locale/en/shop.json))**

```
{
    "default_user_name": "User",
    "provide_delivery_address": "%s, please enter the delivery address for these flowers. Include apartment # if needed.",
    "confirm_choice": "Great choice \"%s\"! Delivery on %s"
}
```